# How do I censor an answer to a question through Google forms?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using a webhook with discord to display the results in a discord channel. My form has a login using matching expressions. This login includes an email. I want this email censored or removed from what is outputted into the discord channel since I don't want people to see what their email is. I know very little about Google Apps Script so I really need help with this. If you know any Javascript I do hope you can help as Google Apps Script is highly based on javascript.

I've tried using an if statement to recognize what the question says and if it says "Email address:" then it changes the answer to blank. This did not work.

```
function onSubmit(e) {

    var POST_URL = "WEBHOOK";
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var allResponses = form.getResponses();
    var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
    var response = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
    var items = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
        var answer = response[i].getResponse();
        try {
            var parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];
        } catch (e) {
            var parts = answer;
        }

        if (answer == "") {
            continue;
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
              if (question == "Email address:"){
              answer = " ";
              }
                items.push({
                    "name": question,
                    "value": parts[j],
                    "inline": false
                });
            } else {
                items.push({
                    "name": question.concat(" (cont.)"),
                    "value": parts[j],
                    "inline": false
                });
            }
        }
    }


    var params = {
        "method": "post",
        "payload": JSON.stringify({
            "embeds": [{
                "title": "Form",
                "fields": items,
                "footer": {
                    "text": "Form"
                }
            }]
        })
    };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, params);}
```

There are no error messages. I've run the script multiple times and doesn't seem to work. The email is still displayed in the discord channel.

Comment: Your code example is incomplete.  There are non matching brackets.

Comment: I am not able to follow through all of your code but when you iterate through all of the questions and answers, when you find the one that is for e-mail, before you push it on `items`, remove everything after the `@` -- for example `answer.split("@")[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the responses with `getItemResponses()` you receive an array of the responses of the form, in the same order as the questions. A solution to your problem would be to change the email question to the top of the form, and begin your loop after it: `for (var i = 1; i < response.length; i++) {...`

To avoid changing your form, you can just keep track of which question is the email, you can check by listing your responses in the logs with `Logger.log(response[i].getResponse() + "  " + i);` and then using that i to skip the email entry in your loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    if (i == x)
        continue;
...
```

This, where x is the index of the email, would simply skip the entry with the email and continue with the rest of the questions, hope this was able to help!